Black hole collision with a probe
I understand that for an outside observer it will take an infinite amount of time for an infalling object to reach the black-hole event horizon.
Consider a black hole that orbits around the center of the galaxy and far from it (far like our sun). There is a non-moving (relative to the galactic center) probe located somewhere on the black-hole's orbit.
Is there a paradox here – the black-hole should hit the probe in a finite amount of time, but on the other hand, it will take an infinite time for the probe to fall (once near) into the black-hole?

I think the observer would see the probe get captured by the black hole's gravity and fall arbitrarily close to the black hole, but never actually cross.

From an outsider's perspective an object would fall toward and then freeze at the horizon and redshift to invisibility very quickly. So what a human being actually sees would look basically indistinguishable from just "falling in" and vanishing. You would need a very elaborate high speed sensor array to detect the difference.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21319/123208

Key point of order: the Schwarzschild metric is only valid in the rest frame of the black hole. The coordinate system used would be changed by a shift to any other IFoR, and so would the metric. For this reason also, one cannot say that an object accelerated to sufficiently near the speed of light would become a black hole: the Schwarzschild metric deals with the rest mass of the object in its rest frame.
To consider what would happen to the probe being “hit”, try switching to the black hole’s comoving frame and seeing what the probe’s new trajectory looks like. Whatever happens in that frame is what would be observed, albeit changed by a translation/rotation/boost, by anyone else. Trying to apply the regular Schwarzschild gravitational effects while the BH is moving would result in strange effects.

The event horizon is moving toward the probe so the external observer concludes that it will hit the probe in finite time. Therefore "seeing" that the probe never hit the horizon is optical illusion? As if the horizon is "pushing" the probe away from it?

I would imagine that's what you'd observe, yeah. In the BH's comoving frame, the trajectory the probe has is just one with a high initial velocity (whatever the RV between the orbiting BH and probe is) that still is radially-infalling. The probe will of course then come to apparent near-rest just outside the EH; translate into a frame where the BH is moving and there's a fictitious pushing force. Couldn't tell you what the geodesics look like without calculations, but that's the qualitative answer.

@RaniSharoni “As if the horizon is ‘pushing’ the probe away from it?” - Yes, exactly. This is quite obvious by changing the frame to the black hole, as this answer suggests. The effect of the horizon pushing objects is called the linear frame dragging. It happens when the horizon moves, changes shape, or expands. Also, the horizon does not have to be the event horizon. The same happens with the apparent horizon (which is what most people really mean when they refer to the event horizon). Also, this is not an optical illusion. The horizon actually pushes objects.

From the POV of the probe, where compared to the galaxy-center does it hit the EH?
From the POV of external observer, does it see the probe spinning with the BH around the galaxy-center due to frame dragging?
Isn't that a paradox?

@RaniSharoni It's very common in relativity that different reference frames/coordinate systems measure things differently. But just measuring different things isn't a paradox, it's known for example that in the probe's frame, it passes through the horizon in finite time while from the outside an observer measures an infinite time for that to happen. This sounds like a contradiction but really it is just an extreme example of how in relativity the same events can have very different descriptions, in different coordinate systems.

I thought that if two objects (or photons) do collide then all observers agree on the location in space where it happens for consistency of nature.

@RaniSharoni Localized spacetime events is one thing everyone must agree about, if that's what you mean. The problem here is, that what happens at the horizon for the falling observer is that his spatial coordinate becomes time-like. This implies it becomes much less intuitive to relate spacetime events between an observer on the outside of the BH and himself. This at least is my qualitative understanding of it, but I know this definitely doesn't lead to a paradox. From the theoretical standpoint, it really comes down to a very unintuitive relation between different coordinate systems.

The unintuitive part is that although the BH is moving toward the probe and also gravitationally pulling it, the probe is actually being pushed (dragged) away.

@RaniSharoni Why? The moment you accept the general notion that in the rest frame of the BH, objects appear to get "frozen", redshifted, etc. as they approach the EH, the "pushing" you mention is just the effect of transforming to a frame where the BH has some relative velocity. To use a very rough analogy, if you accept that a bug gets squashed on your car's windshield, you also have to accept it squashed and moving (being "pushed") at 50kmh for someone on the sidewalk.

@RaniSharoni “From the POV of external observer, does it see the probe spinning with the BH around the galaxy-center due to frame dragging?” - You may have misinterpreted my frame dragging comment above. There are two types of frame dragging, rotational and linear. In this case it is linear that has nothing to do with the probe spinning around the galaxy. A black hole hits the probe and pushes it off by dragging it forward linearly in front of the horizon. As observed from outside, the probe never reaches the horizon.

From the POV of the probe time is ticking slower so the BH time-space “capsule” seems to be moving faster around the galaxy-center (linear momentum)?
This is consistent with external observer seeing that the probe is being pushed aways by the EH (while never hitting it)?
I wonder if there is something physical that pushes the probe (gravitons?).

In Einsteinain gravity it would just be the curvature of spacetime; things need not force impressed upon them to accelerate if space is curved. In quantum gravity, it would be a curvature of the graviton tensor field, yes.
